# Native splash screen width and height

Tags: android, ios, flutter, splash-screen

I'm using [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) to create native splash screen for both android and ios but i need to specify the height and width of my app logo which appears in this splash screen because i'm using the same logo for some animation in the next screen, so i need them to be in the same width and height

Update 1

this is the code of the image i'm using in the next screen

```
AnimatedAlignPositioned(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds:500),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                moveByChildHeight: change ? -0.5 : 0,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/splash.png',
                  width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(250),
                  height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(250),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium,
                ),
              ),
```